# MingW doesn't generate object file; what am I doing wrong?

Tags: windows, gcc, mingw, mingw-w64, msys2

I just installed mingw64 in my msys2 env on Win11. The compiler does not produce an object file when compiling a trivial file:

foo.c:

```
int i;
```

```
% /mingw64/bin/gcc -v -c foo.c
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-12.2.0/configure --prefix=/mingw64 --with-local-prefix=/mingw64/local --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --with-native-system-header-dir=/mingw64/include --libexecdir=/mingw64/lib --enable-bootstrap --enable-checking=release --with-arch=nocona --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=c,lto,c++,fortran,ada,objc,obj-c++,jit --enable-shared --enable-static --enable-libatomic --enable-threads=posix --enable-graphite --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts --enable-libstdcxx-time --disable-libstdcxx-pch --enable-lto --enable-libgomp --disable-multilib --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/mingw64 --with-mpfr=/mingw64 --with-mpc=/mingw64 --with-isl=/mingw64 --with-pkgversion='Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project' --with-bugurl=https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --disable-libstdcxx-debug --with-boot-ldflags=-static-libstdc++ --with-stage1-ldflags=-static-libstdc++
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-c' '-mtune=generic' '-march=nocona'
 C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/cc1.exe -quiet -v -iprefix C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/ -D_REENTRANT foo.c -quiet -dumpbase foo.c -dumpbase-ext .c -mtune=generic -march=nocona -version -o C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\ccF8KQyo.s
% ls -l
-a---    7  3 Feb 15:57 foo.c
%
```

As you can see it just outputs an assembly file into %TMP%. No errors or warnings (compiling without `-v` produces nothing on stdout/stderr).

I must have something misconfigured, but not sure what. I have reviewed previous SO answers but they are about source code with errors or warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you need to have `/mingw64/bin` in `$PATH` or it fails silently in this way. Solved.

Comment: You shouldn't need to add it manually. Starting MINGW64 shell should add it automatically.